# Calculate time taken for XML File conversion

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am creating a tool for a XML file convertor. The schema for the XML file is changing and the tool will take the xml file in format A and convert it to format B.(there is a huge change in the schema stucture).

Is there any way to calculate the amount of time it will take for the file conversion? Is there any standard method/formula?(depending on the size of the file etc)

(File size can go upto 4GB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identify a couple of size classes, like.

- <100M
- <1G
- <4G

Parse a couple of random exemplary files for each size class, take the total time for each class and divide with the amount of files to get the average.

Now take the numbers that you calculated and apply to the rest of the files by multiplying with the amount of files in each class.

Requires minimal control and gives you a reasonable estimate.

With some knowledge of the document type, you could also group them by that, since different document structures tend to take varying time.

**Real Time Progress**

This is a pretty neat trick you could use, overlay whatever reader class you will be using by your own implementation that forwards any read calls while logging the amount that was requested. Given that you know the size of the file you now have a way of displaying progress (i.e. a percentage, or part out of total).

Since parsing is usually what takes most time with xml processing this, this should give you a good indication of how fast it is working.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is at the start of the conversion code store the system time in miliiseconds

And at the completion of the conversion code again take the system time in milliseconds and subtract them to get the time spent in conversion (in milliseconds)

```
public void yourConversionMethod(){
      //start of method
      long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      ....
      ....
      //your conversion code
      ...
      ...
      //end of method
      long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

      long conversionTime = end - start;
}
```

Comment: yes, this is a way but this is possible only after the operation is compelete
Actually what I need is something similar to this: when we are downloading a file from the net,even as the download is taking place we get a message saying 40 min left etc. I need something similar to that

Comment: that depends on the network speed and the file size., what you need to do in that case is to divide the file size by the network speed to get the time left.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your transformation is linear: that is, doubling the size of the input doubles the length of time. (If it's not linear, then handling 4Gb files won't be easy).

Then measure the speed: say 10Mb/sec. The speed you achieve will depend greatly on the nature of the transformation, on the efficiency of your coding, and on the technology you are using.

Then extrapolate from the file size.

The big problem if you need to handle sizes up to 4GB is that you need to use a streaming transformation (one which doesn't hold the whole file in memory) and this (a) limits your choice of technologies (very few XSLT processors offer streaming capability, and those that do cost money), and (b) makes the transformation a lot more difficult to code.